# Could I combine two closures in groovy?

Tags: groovy, closures

I have one closure:

```
def Boolean check(String name, String value, Context c){
   c.name.equalsIgnoreCase(value);
}
```

There is a get method to get the closure:

```
def getClosure() {
    check
}
```

I am trying to get the Logical disjunction of two calls (name could be "Dog" or "Cat"):

```
c1 = check.curry("name", "Dog");
c2 = check.curry("name", "Cat");

c3 = c1 || c2; /*Could this closure be created?*/

Context ctx = new Context();
c3.call(ctx);
```

My question is is there a way to create a c3 closure?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use guava predicates? As you're currying down to a single argument closure, they should just map cleanly across with a groovy `as`

Comment: `c3.call(ctx)` should return either `['Dog', 'Cat']`, `['Dog']` or `['Cat']`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that Groovy ships with a combinator for or'ing predicates (if that's what you are asking). You'll probably have to do `c3 = { c1(it) || c2(it) }`.